# .htaccess (I think) - RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a number of URL that I want to point to a single page but need to display the relevant URL when the page opens and not the actual URL of the page;

e.g. page address is `http://example.com/pagename.php`

but I also have the url's `aaa.com`, `bbb.com`, `ccc.com` etc.

When some uses `aaa.com` I want to display `http://example.com/pagename.php` but show `aaa.com` in the browser.

I'm sure this is a "simple" `RewriteRule` but I don't play with `.htaccess`, any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa.com$ example.com/pagename.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: OK, that looks exactly what I want, really simple if you know what your doing:) thanks

Comment: its very specific you can do lot more with it

Comment: Yadav just realised - assume it works aswell can "pagename.php" have a get variable i,e, pagename.php?var=X

Comment: yeah it works fot it too

Comment: for tht we have to modify it

Comment: `xxx.com/pagename.php?var=X` same as `aaa.com?var=X `

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help, just make sure that there's an **Apache HTTP Server** with `mod_rewrite` on your web hosting account, then use these configuration directives in your `.htaccess` hidden file that therein the root:

```
# once per htaccess file
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/pagename.php [P]
```

But remember, this kind of question is belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use absolute paths, assuming all the sites are on the same server... For `aaa.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?aaa\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Absolute/Path/To/Root/Directory/For/example.com/$1
```

For `bbb.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bbb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Absolute/Path/To/Root/Directory/For/example.com/$1
```

... etc.

Note: this also assumes that the absolute path to `example.com`'s root directory is `/Absolute/Path/To/Root/Directory/For/example.com/` (but maybe that was obvious)... ;)